# Single Fragment throughout application

Tags: android, fragment

Is there any way to use single fragment with different layouts?

In my application I want only single fragment with single activity. I went through a lot of solutions but didn't get any specified solutions.

Comment: What do you want to do with single fragment? I dont think your solution is best solution. Express it if you need help!

Comment: I think using single fragment with different layouts will optimize your application throughput. In my application there is only one fragment will show at a time, so why to create different-2 fragment class for this purpose, that is why I want to use single fragment for this purpose.

Comment: :)) I dont think 1 class do everything is good practice. In my opinion, you should not do it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but if I want to do this then there is any why to do that.